# perl if elsif return - compilation error

Tags: perl, if-statement, return

I have the following subroutine which produces this error but I don't understand why:

Not enough arguments for main::formatdate at C:...pl line 44, near ""May")"
Execution of C:...pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Code:

```
sub formatdate($month) {

  if    ($month eq "Jan") {return ".01.";}
  elsif ($month eq "Feb") {return ".02.";}
  elsif ($month eq "Mar") {return ".03.";}
  elsif ($month eq "Apr") {return ".04.";}
  elsif ($month eq "May") {return ".05.";}
  elsif ($month eq "Jun") {return ".06.";}
  elsif ($month eq "Jul") {return ".07.";}
  elsif ($month eq "Aug") {return ".08.";}
  elsif ($month eq "Sep") {return ".09.";}
  elsif ($month eq "Oct") {return ".10.";}
  elsif ($month eq "Nov") {return ".11.";}
  elsif ($month eq "Dec") {return ".12.";}
  else                    {return "N/A";}
}

print formatdate("May");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [`perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html)

You can fix this by changing:

```
sub formatdate($month) {
```

To the following:

```
sub formatdate {
    my $month = shift;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to define your `formatdate` is

```
sub formatdate {
  my($month) = @_;
```

Also, you might want to update your print statement to include a newline

```
print formatdate("May") . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading [`perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) is the advice that you need to fix your subroutine.

However, I'd like to further advise you to recognize the use of a hash whenever you have key/value pairs like you're using.  In the below code, I manually specified the hash, but one could also build the hash very easily using just a list of month names:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub formatdate {
    my $month = shift;

    my %monthcode = qw(
        Jan    .01.
        Feb    .02.
        Mar    .03.
        Apr    .04.
        May    .05.
        Jun    .06.
        Jul    .07.
        Aug    .08.
        Sep    .09.
        Oct    .10.
        Nov    .11.
        Dec    .12.
    );

    return $monthcode{$month} || 'N/A';
}

print formatdate("May");
```

Outputs:

```
.05.
```